# Looking for name of problem similar to Steiner trees but with an RGB balancing constraint (color code decoding)

Tags: reference-request

In quantum computing, there is an error correcting code called the color code where each error in the bulk of the code produces three types of symptoms (one red, one green, one blue). Pairs of errors can push a symptom of one color around. The task of decoding is to find a minimal set of errors that merge the given symptoms back into each other.

The actual solutions are reminiscent of Steiner trees, where the errors may be pushed to some common middle meeting point instead of directly towards each other. There are two major difference compared to the Steiner tree problem. First, the virtual nodes are always degree 3 and always merge exactly one symptom of each color. This heavily constraints what you can merge. Second, it's not necessary to merge the entire set of nodes into one connected component. It just needs to be the case that each connected component ends up with neutral charge (the same number of red, green, and blue nodes modulo 2).

Rephrasing a bit:

- You're given a set of nodes colored red, green, and blue.
- Your goal is to draw red, green, and blue curves linking the nodes together into a forest.
- You must minimize the total length of curve.
- Curves can only stop at the given nodes or at virtual nodes.
- The given nodes must each have exactly one curve of that node's color (and no other curves) stopping at it.
- Each virtual node must have exactly one curve of each color stopping at it.
- It is promised that num_red = num_green = num_blue (mod 2), which guarantees a solution exists.

**My question is: does this problem already exist in the literature and have a name?** Is it known if it's NP complete? In the quantum computing world this is known as a color code decoding, but it seems plausible that it might have other names elsewhere.

Comment: I did not understand the first and second paragraph, maybe because I am not too familiar with error correcting codes. Is is required or it is just for the motivation?

Regarding the rephrased question. Is the input to the problem a graph?. By curve, do you mean edges?

Comment: @InuyashaYagami the problem can be solved on a graph with some nodes colored as the problem input, or on the Euclidean plane with some colored points specified as the input.